# Cannot understand how new or malloc does work with BYTE*

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

I trying to allocate memory for 10 bytes

```
BYTE* tmp;
tmp = new BYTE[10];
//or tmp = (BYTE*)malloc(10*sizeof(BYTE));
```

But after new or malloc operation length of *tmp more than 10 (i.e. '\0' char not in 10 position in tmp array)

Why?

Comment: Since you are trying to represent a string, and I see that you have tagged this C++, you should probably use std::string, instead of char* or BYTE* (I'm assuming BYTE is your own typedef).

Answer (score 8):

Neither `new[]` nor `malloc()` will place the `\0` for you. When you call `malloc()` or `new[]` for `char` the block is unitilialized - you need to initialize it manually - either put `\0` into the last element, or use `memset()` for the entire block.

Comment: There is one more way to initialize array with 0: new BYTE[10](). See my answer for details.

Answer (score 6):

There is no reason for `'\0'` to be at the end of the array.

malloc (or new, for that matter), gives you back a block of 10 bytes, which is memory it allocated for you. It's **your** job to do whatever you want with this memory.

You're probably getting mixed up with a string (like `char[10]`, for example).

The whole idea of a string is to be an array of bytes, but which ends with `'\0'` to denote its size.

An array of bytes, or any **other** array you allocate which isn't a string, won't neceassrily end with `'\0'`; it's **your** job to keep track of its size.

Answer (score 1):

First, BYTE array can contains zeros, thats why you can't use strlen to determine array length.

Second, after calling new BYTE[10] your arrray remains uninitalized (contains garbage) if you want automaticly initalize array with 0 you can use the following code:

```
BYTE* tmp2;
tmp2 = new BYTE[10]();
```

But even in this case you can't use strlen, because strlen returns 0.

You must save array length into some variable or simply use std::vector instead.